# Using onload with append images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending multiple images to multiple divs.

```
$('.wrap').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<img src="img1.jpg"/><img src="img.jpg"/>');
});
```

how can I do an onload to the images? Basically I need to fire `done();` when all images complete loading.

Comment: What does `load` mean? Image's `load`?

Comment: put ur done function after each function

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks. I just edited my post. Basically I'm looking for a away to run `done();` when all images complete loading.

Answer (score 1):

Since the images are dynamically appended, you can do this, assuming the `.wrap` is static:

```
$(".wrap").on("load", "img", function () {
  // this -> refers to `img` that's been added just now.
  done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. `.wrap` is dynamic.

Comment: @Becky Then use another static parent... `:)`

Comment: What about `$('.element').each(function () { }).promise().done(function () { });` ?